# How to get the name of buttons saved in a variable (present in python flask code) whenever the buttons are clicked?

Tags: python, html, json, flask

Website interface:
[image]

Example: "VNA 1" is clicked by the user on website

Python code:

variable = VNA 1

Answer (score 0):

In your select->option tag in html, pass the value like this:

```
<select id="select" name="select" class="form-control">
<option id="id1" value="VNA1">VNA1</option>
```

Your form should hit the appropriate POST url.

```
<form id="form1" class="col-xl-12 md-float-material form-material" action="/postU" method="POST"></form>
```

The submit-button tag will then pass the value of select tag into the flask route which you can capture as:

```
value = request.form.get('select')
```